# Сортировка массива по группам одного из значений

Tags: массивы, html, php, сортировка

Есть массив:

```
                                                    array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(2) "30"
    ["ShowInCompare"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["ShowInFilter"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ShowOnSite"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["MainProperty"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(16) "Гарантия"
    ["Desc"]=>
    string(39) "Общие характеристики"
    ["Value"]=>
    string(15) "24 месяца"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(2) "29"
    ["ShowInCompare"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["ShowInFilter"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["ShowOnSite"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["MainProperty"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(25) "Видео формати"
    ["Desc"]=>
    NULL
    ["Value"]=>
    string(14) "AVI, ASF, BDMV"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(2) "28"
    ["ShowInCompare"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["ShowInFilter"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["ShowOnSite"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["MainProperty"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(26) "Аудио форматы "
    ["Desc"]=>
    NULL
    ["Value"]=>
    string(13) "AAC, AC3, DTS"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(8) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(2) "20"
    ["ShowInCompare"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["ShowInFilter"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["ShowOnSite"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["MainProperty"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(35) "Технология дисплея"
    ["Desc"]=>
    string(10) "Экран"
    ["Value"]=>
    string(3) "LCD"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(8) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(2) "21"
    ["ShowInCompare"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["ShowInFilter"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ShowOnSite"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["MainProperty"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(25) "Размер экрана"
    ["Desc"]=>
    string(10) "Экран"
    ["Value"]=>
    string(2) "21"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(8) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(2) "22"
    ["ShowInCompare"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["ShowInFilter"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["ShowOnSite"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["MainProperty"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(4) "HDMI"
    ["Desc"]=>
    string(10) "Экран"
    ["Value"]=>
    string(4) "Да"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(8) {
    ["Id"]=>
    string(2) "23"
    ["ShowInCompare"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["ShowInFilter"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ShowOnSite"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["MainProperty"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["Name"]=>
    string(16) "Мощность"
    ["Desc"]=>
    string(39) "Общие характеристики"
    ["Value"]=>
    string(9) "1500 Вт"
  }
}
```

Нужно вывести этот массив таким образом:

```
<h3>Монитор</h3><br> <!-- Desc -->
<b>Дигональ:</b> 17<br> <!-- Name Value -->
<b>Разрешение:</b> 1024х768<br><br><!-- Name Value -->

<h3>Оперативная память</h3><br> <!-- Desc -->
<b>Объём:</b> 1024<br> <!-- Name Value -->
<b>Частота:</b> 1033<br> <!-- Name Value -->
```

То есть сгруппировать массив, опираясь на `Desc`. Как можно это реализовать?

Comment: Прямо такой массив и есть? С двумя одинаковыми ключами? И что значит - "опираясь на group"? Как угадать, какое именно разрешение должно быть при group == Монитор? И почему в оперативной памяти именно 1024 (не 1024Мб)? И почему нельзя было сделать группировку при формировании массива?

Comment: Ну, во-первых, (ИМХО) само использование массива (и такого массива) с точки зрения архитектуры для такого рода решений выглядит не совсем уместным. Но если уж извращаться, то само простое в таком случае (и если, тем более, массив большой) - брать каждый индекс, точнее его содержание (вложенный массив), и заливать его, вложенного элемента, значения в таблицу базы, из которой элементарным `SELECT`-ом можно доставать данные и группировать результат как заблагорассудится.

Comment: ассоциативный массив лучше сделайте, иначе придется все характеристики пробегать, чтобы найти нужную. К тому же в вашем массиве я не вижу слова "Дигональ", Диагональ тоже не вижу.
Hint: храните характеристики/товары в трех таблицах:

    Товар:    ID,Товар,Цена
    Характеристики: ID,Имя,Описание
    Товар-Характеристики: ID_Товара,ID_Характеристики,значение характеристики.

Comment: Я вот и не знаю, как мне сделать ассоциативный массив правильно. Я получаю его в таком виде из БД, а что дальше делать с ним чтобы сделать ассоциативным не понимаю.

Comment: так почему вы в таком виде то храните что так получаете ? ну поменяйте в этом массиве цифру на поле Name, и будет вам ассоциативный.

Comment: Ну вообще в 3х таблицах и храню, просто запросом их связываю потом:
    [code]$property = SPropertiesQuery::create()
                ->joinSProductPropertiesData()
                ->where('SProductPropertiesData.ProductId = ?', $product->getId())
                ->select(array('Id', 'ShowInCompare', 'ShowInFilter', 'ShowOnSite', 'ShowInFilter', 'MainProperty', 'SPropertiesI18n.Name', 'SPropertiesI18n.Description'))
                ->groupBy('SProductPropertiesData.PropertyId')
                ->orderByPosition()->find()->toArray();[/code]

Comment: вот если вместо того чтобы вызывать метод ->toArray() вызвать fetch по одному и сложить  массив как хочется ? какой там фреймворк ?

Comment: CodeIgniter, система ImageCMS Shop, не совсем понял про fetch

Comment: я имел ввиду вместо 

$propery= ... ->toArray();

сделать сначала $result и потом перебрать его.

Comment: В этом и заключался вопрос. Как правильно перебрать этот массив. Я задачу решил, сначала перебрал массив, и создал новый включающий в себя только Desc, потом начал перебирать этот новый массив, а в нём перебирать основной массив и проверять значение Desc в нём, но это слишком замутно, может есть варианты проще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно пригодится [uasort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) ?

Вот [пример](http://pastebin.com/NP0MX0rY) использования.

```
<?php
$data = array(
    array(
        'id'    => 1,
        'name'  => 'bbb',
        'desc'  => 'zzz'
    ),
    array(
        'id'    => 2,
        'name'  => 'aaa',
        'desc'  => 'yyy'
    ),
    array(
        'id'    => 3,
        'name'  => 'qqq',
        'desc'  => 'bbb'
    ),
    array(
        'id'    => 4,
        'name'  => 'fff',
        'desc'  => 'kkk'
    )
);

echo '<b>Исходный массив</b>:';
echo'<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre><br><hr><br>';

echo 'Отсортировано по ID:';
uasort($data, function($first, $second){
    return ($first['id'] >= $second['id']);
});
echo'<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre><br><hr><br>';

echo 'Отсортировано по `name`:';
uasort($data, function($first, $second){
    return ($first['name'] >= $second['name']);
});
echo'<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre><br><hr><br>';

echo 'Отсортировано по `desc`:';
uasort($data, function($first, $second){
    return ($first['desc'] >= $second['desc']);
});
echo'<pre>'.print_r($data, true).'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array('1000','1000','1500','2500','2500');          
        $n=0;        
        foreach($arr as $k=>$v){      
            $new_arr[$n][] = $v;    
            if($arr[$k] != $arr[$k+1]){$n++;}   
            }
        foreach($new_arr as $o){var_dump( $o);echo 'br';}
```

вот решение - получаем новый массив с собранными по значению массивами внутри